# MySQL Join three different results and count

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Got three results extracted from three different tables.

Each table is a product: `loans`, `credits` and `discounts`.

loans and credits got the following data: `clientid`, `type`, `productid`, `date` & `expiration` (days to go).
discounts got: `clientid`, `date` and `expiration`.

The results are the number of times (count) for every client which product expires in 10 days (or less) and is registered among two dates.
Example (just for loans):

```
SELECT clientid, COUNT(*)
FROM loans
WHERE ((type LIKE 'TITULAR') AND(date BETWEEN 'ccyy-mm-dd' AND 'ccyy-mm-dd') AND (expires <= 10))
GROUP BY clientid
ORDER BY clientid;
```

Obviously, not all the clients got loans, credits or discounts at the same time, but I need to get a result that sums the number of times any client has any of the products expiring in 10 days or less among the limit dates.

So, in example, if client #200 got 3 loans, 2 credits and just one discount; all of them between date1 and date2, with expiration equal or less 10; the result should be 6.

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT loansr.clienteid, (loansr.count + creditsr.count + discountsr.count)
FROM
    (SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "count"
    FROM loans
    WHERE (type LIKE 'TITULAR') 
    AND (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires <= 10)
    GROUP BY clienteid) loansr,
    (SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "count"
    FROM credits
    WHERE (type LIKE 'TITULAR') 
    AND (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires <= 10)
    GROUP BY clienteid) creditsr,
    (SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "count"
    FROM discounts
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires <= 10)
    GROUP BY clienteid) discountsr
WHERE
    (loansr.clienteid = creditsr.clienteid = discountsr.clienteid)
ORDER BY loansr.clienteid;
```

Edit 18:25
I've think that if I use UNION ALL to mix the three results and then group by clienteid I will get what I'm looking for, won't I?

```
SELECT clienteid AS "CLIENTE", SUM(COUNT) AS  "NUM_VECES_INCI_10_ACT_U3M" FROM
    ((SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "COUNT"
    FROM loans
    WHERE (titularidad_tipo LIKE 'TITULAR') 
    AND (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires >= 11)
    GROUP BY clienteid)
        UNION ALL
    (SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "COUNT"
    FROM credits
    WHERE (titularidad_tipo LIKE 'TITULAR') 
    AND (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires >= 11)
    GROUP BY clienteid)
        UNION ALL
    (SELECT clienteid, COUNT(*) AS "COUNT"
    FROM discounts
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-30')
    AND (expires >= 11)
    GROUP BY clienteid)) orig
GROUP BY clienteid
ORDER BY clienteid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd post it in the comment if I could :)
If you use UNION ALL, you should get the desired results. Although make sure to have proper indexes (I suggest titularidad_tipo, date, expires) for tables loansr, credits, and (date, expires) for discounts table. If you have proper indexation, your results will come quickly.